# java iterate through properties file

Tags: java, smtp

I have a project to send emails via a Java Application.
I have almost everything working, I just need to be able to configure the number of emails I send.

I have all of the email addresses in a Properties File. The application spec requires me to set a value in this file that will determine the number of emails to send. Here is an example of my properties file, in the hope that this helps:

```
email1=tom@foo.com
email2=jerry@foo.com
email3=spike@foo.com
iterate=1  //this is the value that needs to be changed 
           in order to decide the number of emails to send.
```

In my application code, I have the following:

**Application**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
String to = props.getProperty("to");
String from = props.getProperty("from");
String host = props.getProperty("host");
String port = props.getProperty("port);

props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);

try
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject("<subject goes here>");
        message.setText(<body goes here>);
        Transport.send(message);
    }
```

Comment: So can you not use `properties.get("iterate")` and then `Integer.parseInt`?

Comment: @JonSkeet how do you mean? I need to be able to configure the number of emails to send with the "iterate" key. Do you have an example of how I can do this using my code?

Comment: Well that basically *is* the code to get the `iterate` value out of a properties file and then parse it as an integer. What bit of it do you not understand?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I derped. I have part of the solution now. I just need to split the single email key into 3 elements now, according to @atish shimpi's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put all your email id against single key

```
emails=tom@foo.com,jerry@foo.com,spike@foo.com
```

Then read this `emails` string and split it into to array.

Then read `iterate`, and execute your for loop on email array upto no of `iterate` present in your properties file.

Edited

If this email id's for `to` emails

```
String emails = props.getProperty("emails);
String iterate = Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty("iterate));
String arr[]= emails.split(",");
String toArr[] = new String[iterate];
System.arraycopy(arr, 0, toArr, 0, iterate);
```

now you have `toArr` array, using this `toArr` send your email's

Comment: Using http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html and commaDelimitedListToSet you have the set of emails.

Comment: @atish Shimpi do you have an example I can use?

Comment: please post your code, for getting properties file and setting it to your email address

Comment: @jjlema Good suggestion but for this I cannot use spring.

So far I have an array that will not split into three elements, based on atish's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help @atishshimpi, but I found that the line "System.arraycopy(arr, 0, toArr, 0, iterate)" is a little redundant, as arr and toArr (when printed with a valid index) identical, so no need to copy from one to the other.